# Is there a way to overload a SlashCommand?

Tags: c#, discord, discord.net

I'm trying to set up a Discord bot with some slash commands.  The nature of the commands is such that it's useful to make them work in a few different ways based on different inputs, which maps well to the concept of overloaded methods.  So I tried this:

```
using Discord.Interactions;
using Newtonsoft.Json;

namespace MyBot
{
    public class Quotes : InteractionModuleBase<SocketInteractionContext>
    {
        private static readonly QuoteData[] _quotes;
        private static readonly Random _rng = new();

        static Quotes ()
        {
            var json = File.ReadAllText(Path.Combine("Data", "quotes.json"));
            _quotes = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<QuoteData[]>(json)!;
        }

        [SlashCommand("quote", "Quote a famous quotation from history")]
        public async Task Quote()
        {
            var result = _quotes[_rng.Next(_quotes.Length)];
            await RespondAsync(result.Text);
        }

        [SlashCommand("quote", "Quote a specific quote from the list")]
        public async Task Quote(int index)
        {
            if (index > 0 && index <= _quotes.Length) {
                await RespondAsync_quotes[index - 1]);
            } else {
                await RespondAsync("We don't have a quote with that number.");
            }
        }
    }
}
```

When I try to run the bot, though, I get an error:

> A Ready handler has thrown an unhandled exception.:
>
> System.InvalidOperationException: A Discord.Interactions.SlashCommandInfo already exists with the same name: quote

So if I can't overload a `[SlashCommand]` this way, what's the proper way to do it so that I can respond to different inputs with different methods?  (Hopefully without having to write my own parser.)

Comment: Slash commands are registered with Discord. You can't register multiple commands with the same name. You'd either use multiple commands or a single command with optional parameters.

Answer (score 2):

You could move to a single method and give index a default value in the overload.

```
[SlashCommand("quote", "Receive a quote")]
public async Task Quote(int index = 0)
{
    if (index == 0)
    {
        var result = _quotes[_rng.Next(_quotes.Length)];
        await RespondAsync(result.Text);
    }
    else
    {
        if (index <= _quotes.Length)
        {
            await RespondAsync_quotes[index - 1]);
        }
        else
        {
            await RespondAsync("We don't have a quote with that number.");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: This works for this specific example, but doesn't really solve the general problem of handling arbitrary sets of different inputs.  What if I wanted a third version that takes a string?

Comment: I think this is simply a limitation of the SlashCommand pattern. At that point, you're either changing the overload to a string and adding int.TryParse to the method and handling all 3 routes, or resigning yourself to several different commands and methods.